# Issue converting geojson file to vector tile(s) using mapbox-tile-copy

Tags: python, mapbox, geojson, vector-tiles

So I have tried to follow the instructions in the README for mapbox-tile-copy at the following url: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-tile-copy

Right now I am in the project root directory where the geojson file exists and where a folder called tester exists that I want the vector tiles saved in. I try running the following command, which seems like it should work:

```
mapbox-tile-copy gjson.geojson file://./tester
```

but this gives the error:

```
Unknown filetype
```

I'm not sure what it is complaining about here. I guessed the geojson filetype is unknown but mapbox-tile-copy specifically says they support geojson AND give examples of it working. Could it be the geojson file is not in the correct structure or something? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities here:

1. Your geojson file is improperly formatted
2. mapbox-tile-copy is implicitly trying to convert to a tile structure

I believe #1 is the most likely, but I'm mentioning 2 just in case.

For #1, you can use a tool like http://geojsonlint.com/ to quickly see if there's a problem with your .geojson file.

I mention #2 because, based on the examples given in the [usage section](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-tile-copy#usage) of the tools README.md, it looks like the expectation when you provide a `.geojson` is that this will be converted into vector tiles. So you might need to specify some `{z}/{x}/{y}` parameters in your output argument. Like so:

```
mapbox-tile-copy gjson.geojson file://./tester/{z}/{x}/{y}
```

Comment: Thanks! it seems as though my issue was the integrity of my geojson and it wasn't actually geojson structure, i tried mapbox-tile-copy gjson.geojson file://./tester/ and mapbox-tile-copy gjson.geojson file://./tester/{z}/{x}/{y} on an example valid geojson file and both worked.